# How i can implement Custom TabHost different with different icons sizes?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a custom TabHost at the bottom of the screen, i have used it before in one of my Apps. i was able to customize it. the only issue i have right now is that i have to make some of the icons in the tab host have different height and maintain the transparent background of the tab host.!
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/31/2l0.png/

1- the bar have a transparent background and  button size is more bigger than the other buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use below layout in tab container xml and modify according to your need:






<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tabbarContainer"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabbarContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/menubg"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/first"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/firstImageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/home_normal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/second"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/secondImageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/trackme_normal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/third"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/menuhover"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/thirdImageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/alarm_active" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/thirdTextView"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fourth"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/fourImageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/feelgood_normal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fourTextView"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fifth"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/fifthImageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/setting_normal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fifthTextView"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circleshape_red"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: Thanks @dharmendra using RelativeLayout did help me :D.